# Running c binary in android using adb

Tags: android, shell, adb, android-ndk-r5

I have created one C binary  named "SocketServer" for android. I pushed the binary into my rooted android phone's /data/local/tmp directory using

> adb shell push SocketServer /data/local/tmp/

I have given permission to the exe using

> adb shell chmod 0777 /data/local/tmp/SocketServer

Now i want to run this ***SocketServer*** executable using a C program running in a windows PC. Need help..

Answer (score 0):

If `/data/local/tmp` is *not* mounted `noexec` (which it **most likely is**), you can run it using:

```
adb shell /data/local/tmp/SocketServer
```

Note that `chmod 777` is **always a bad idea** though, and only Ubuntu people do that…